# How can I create values that outlive 'static lifetime?

Tags: rust

I want to implement `Into` trait for my struct.
`'static` is hinted by the compiler, I do not know why I have to add that.

I hope:

1. invoking into() consumes the `RequestBody` object. (which already did)
2. the references to str inside returned `HashMap` live until the end of scope where into() is invoked.

Below is the error message and code, how can I make it compile as I wish?

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/portal_request.rs:35:9
   |
26 |     fn into(self) -> HashMap<&'static str, &'static str> {
   |             ---- has type `RequestBody<'1>`
...
35 |         list.into_iter().collect()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

```
pub enum BodyEntry<'a> {
    MenuId(&'a str),
    //...
}

pub struct RequestBody<'a> {
    pub entries: Vec<BodyEntry<'a>>,
}

use BodyEntry::*;
impl Into<HashMap<&str, &str>> for RequestBody<'_> {
    fn into(self) -> HashMap<&'static str, &'static str> {
        let mut list = Vec::new();
        for entry in self.entries {
            let entry_literal = match entry {
                MenuId(val) => ("_menuId", val),
                //...
                _ => ("else", "else"),
            };
            list.push(entry_literal);
        }
        list.into_iter().collect()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the lifetimes like so:

```rust
impl<'a> Into<HashMap<&'static str, &'a str>> for RequestBody<'a> {
    fn into(self) -> HashMap<&'static str, &'a str> {
```

Or better:

```rust
impl<'keys, 'a> Into<HashMap<&'keys str, &'a str>> for RequestBody<'a> {
    fn into(self) -> HashMap<&'keys str, &'a str> {
```

Comment: Your code works, but I really want some further explanation on 'static.
Let's call the &str inside the `BodyEntry` enum "val", and call the string literal created inside `into()` "key".
Based on my enum and struct definition, "val" live as long as `BodyEntry` and `RequestBody`. Your two solutions suggest I may either :
1. Simply declare "val" will be value of map, leave key of map static. ( I do not understand )
2. Additionally bind "key" with key of map. ( I understand this )
I wonder if any &str literal has 'static lifetime & why?

Comment: @zhittty String literals are `&'static str`. This is why the first solution works. The second solution works because `&'static str` can be converted to any `&'a str`, because `'static` is bigger than any other lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can't create new `'static` string at runtime. Your keys are fine, because they're all determined at compile-time (at least in this minimal example; if your real example needs dynamically-generated ones then the same caveat applies). But you want to consume the `BodyEntry` and create a `HashMap` which *owns* the strings as values. An owned string is not a `&str`. An owned string is a `String`.

Consider having your `Into` implementation return `HashMap<&str, String>` (again, you might have to change the key type to `String` as well, if your real use case demands it). Then, inside your `match`, consider

```
let entry_literal = match entry {
  MenuId(val) => ("_menuId", String::from(val)),
  //...
  _ => ("else", String::from("else")),
};
```

[`String::from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-From%3C%26str%3E-for-String) copies the underlying `&str` string slice into a new owned `String`.

Comment: It's actually possible to `Box::leak` memory and create `'static` references (including strings) at runtime. Though I agree that's probably not OPs intention.

Comment: Re "`'static` can't be created at runtime", it's worth mentioning: https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program